# Python lambda comprehension print i

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I'm trying to use comprehensions to write a list of lambdas, where each lambda when called will print the index that is it's position in the list.

```py
list = [lambda : print(i) for i in range(10)]

list[0]()
```

But the problem is that calling any of the lambdas all produce the same result, they print 9. How can I capture the value of i in the way I intend to for each lambda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that `i` is evaluated and bound inside the body of the lambda at the time the lambda is *defined*, rather than delaying it until it's *called* (by which time the loop has finished and `i = 9`).  One way of doing that is to use `i` as the default value of a parameter to the lambda, since the default is evaluated when the function is defined rather than when it's called:

```
>>> funcs = [lambda x=i: print(x) for i in range(10)]
>>> funcs[0]()
0
>>> funcs[1]()
1
```

Note that you don't actually need to use a different variable name; you can name the parameter `i` and it will be shadowed inside the lambda body and still work the same way:

```
>>> funcs = [lambda i=i: print(i) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: What other ways would there be to do this?

Comment: A factory function or a class (same difference, really) would be the other way -- something that creates a scope where `i` won't change after the function has been created.